# What is the floor plan of the Huxtable home?

Tags: cosby-show

I'm trying to figure out the placement of all the rooms in the Huxtable home on the Cosby Show. They seem to have following rooms:

- Kitchen
- Living Room
- Formal Dining Room
- 4 Bedrooms? (Master Bedroom and 3 Bedrooms?)
- 3 Bathrooms (including master bath)
- 2 sets of stairs
- Clair's Study (eventually built in the 8th season)

I'm wondering if the layout of the rooms as seen in the sets can be lined up to an actual floor plan. Especially considering all the external shots clearly show the house as being a row house (with houses connected on either side). This means the house should be longer than it is wide.

Comment: There is a website for TV show floorplans: [Fantasy Floorplans](http://www.fantasyfloorplans.com/cart.php?m=search_results&search=cosby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the full floorplans of the Huxtable home from **the Cosby Show**:

---

## First Floor (*Piano Terra*)

[image: First Floor]

- **Formal Dining Room** (Sala Pranzo)
- **Kitchen** (Cucina)
- **Cliff's Studio** (Studio Cliff)
- **Basement** (Cantina)
- **Living Room** (Salotto)
- **Entrance** (Ingresso)

---

## Second Floor (*Primo Piano*)

[image: Second Floor]

- **Bathroom** (*Bagno*)
- **Vanessa & Rudy's Room** (*Vanessa & Rudy*)
- **Theo's Room** (*Camera Theo*)
- **Cliff & Clair's Room** (*Camera Cliff & Clair*)
- **Sondra & Denise's Room** (*Camera Sondra & Denise*)

Comment: I love that this is from an Italian site.

Comment: Not sure of the source (not my answer) I found English versions of the plans, with no attributions, [here](http://blog.suitey.com/cracking-the-code-of-the-cosby-crib/)... so it's possible that this is the source. They are also [here](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/114984). No one seems to want to site sources.

Comment: It's worth noting that "Cliff's Studio" is "Cliff's Practice" on the English maps.

Answer (score 0):

The face of the house we see is from a different place in Brooklyn Heights (?), NY while the interior of the house is a movie studio at Kaufmann Astoria Suites Ney York where the majority of the famous movies were/are filmed.

The floors in the plan or architectural impressions above cannot align because they are an impression of somebody who is not into architecture or who did not use any dimensions when drawing the plan.  It would be good to find out from Kauffman Astoria studios in New York whether they would be willing to share/sell the exact studio/house plan if you really fancy living in a HUXTABLE HOUSE.

Comment: *"The floors in the plan or architectural impressions above cannot align because they are an impression of somebody who is not into architecture or who did not use any dimensions when drawing the plan."* Can you provide reasoning/proof/professional experience to prove this claim?

Comment: @MattD It's pretty obvious... if you stack the two images, they don't overlap.  But this isn't uncommon in TV shows and movies... and it doesn't mean that the plans are wrong... it just means that it's not an actual house.